# event.preventDefault() not working in Hammer.js - window still moves

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, swipe-gesture, hammer.js

the window in mobile Safari moves down making a bounce effect

can this behaviour be stopped with Hammer?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

var statusToggle = Hammer($$(this.pn1)).on("swipedown swipeup", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.gesture.preventDefault()
            SearchRide.toggleStatusbar();
        });
```

adding this will work, but why is it not working in Hammer??

```
 pn1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

thanks